# Really slow wordpress website admin panel with a total query time 1664ms for the home page

Tags: wordpress, mysql, cpu

I have a problem with my WordPress website being too slow, I installed a debug bar to check queries in the home page, it reports 202 queries, and a total query time equal to 1665ms.

[image]

The cpu and the ram are in critical use.

[image]

Here is what i tried to do:

- Optimize pluginDB to defrag the DB.
- ThemeCheck plugin to analyse and clean my template.
- W3C Total cache Plugin with object cachr enabled.

Necessary plugins are:

- WordPress SEO by YOAST
- Jetpack service by WordPress.com
- Contact form 7

Thank you

Comment: Sorry but this question is too board and likely duplicate. Also please note that questions that are too specific may be closed due to the fact they most likely won't help other visitors. You are however welcome to ask this in our chat channel of which myself will most likely leave you a response.

Comment: okey i will check the other post i will check the chat channel

Comment: You might get better luck posting it on wordpress.stackexchange.com :) . Enabling all features on Jetpack is known to cause bloat, so I'd only enable the ones which I use.